# Lexmark E210 Printer install from .ppd file

Tags: catalina, driver, macos

I am excited at the prospect to enable Lexmark E210 printing from Catalina.

The E210 "[Seems to be a relabeled Samsung ML-4500.](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Lexmark/Lexmark-E210)"

PPD file can be downloaded [from this link](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=gdi&printer=Lexmark-E210&.submit=Generate%20PPD%20file&show=1&.cgifields=show&.cgifields=shortgui).  PPD instructions [link](https://www.psn-web.net/cs/support/mfp/common/Mac_PPD_Install_SeculityUtility_en.pdf) for older versions.

I think the PPD file a set of instructions for the OS to download & install the driver?

I think it belongs in:

```
/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources
```

[image]

Yikes!  The .ppd file throws an error:

[image]

Guidance, references, lesson-learned are all appreciated.  I have experience installing Windows drivers, however, this is new territory for me.

## Diagnostic Screenshots for Allan:

Maybe there is a permissions obstacle?

[image]

I suspect that it is necessary to resole the connection error above in order for the .ppd file to execute.  Until then:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work.

The key here is that it uses the [gdi driver](https://www.openprinting.org/driver/gdi); though it's no longer maintained by Samsung, it is is community maintained and appears to have current support.  It's also built into Ghostscript, so it should be there.

The short answer is you should be able to manually add the printer using one of the printer models listed on the driver page (link above).

#### Manually Installing on macOS

The location for the (English) PPD files is `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj`.  Simply copy your PPD file there.

When you Add your printer, the very last field labeled "Use" will be where you specify your driver.  From the drop down, choose "Select Software" (left image).  A list of printer software will open (right image).  Start typing the name of the driver you copied in the filter box at the top; you should find your printer.

[image]  [image]

Note:  In my example, I used "localhost" as I currently don't have the printer hooked up to my network, but you would use the IP address of the printer.  As for protocol, use "LPD" for these older printers.

#### Printer Drivers

One thing you should note is that not all printers are created equal.  It may seem trivial, but depending on engine that drives your printer, you may or may not be able to continue using them.  For example, this printer uses a "Host Based Printing System."

[image]

This means that it's the operating system the local computer that actually does all the rendering of the graphics, not the printer itself.  It's a cost saving move for the manufacturer.  The downside is you have a good chance of this becoming a paperweight down the road.  Fortunately, this was based on a processor from Samsung that had continued support (they also sold this one to Fuji/Xerox)

**Going Forward...**
When purchasing a new printer, be sure to look for a printer that has support for [printing languages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404653/119271) like PCL and/or Postscript.  If it supports both, it's even better!  If it supports emulations like "HP LaserJet" or "Epson" or even "IBM" you can use those generic drivers as well.  These printers do cost a little more, but they make up for it in longevity.

Comment: It's taking me a few minutes to type this.  I'm trying to manually install a Lexmark E260dn and type the steps at the same time.  ;-)

Comment: You are doing a fine job.  I think you are indicating to install the files found here: http://www.openprinting.org/download/printing/samsung-gdi/  however, I am not sure exactly what steps must be executed.  Again thanks!

Comment: That driver should be included since it's built in with Ghostscript.  Try adding the PPD file and see if it works.

Comment: I think you are indicating that position the .ppd file in the en.lproj directory is the only input I need to download for the printer install process?  I will attempt to follow directions & post the results in the original posting

Comment: BTW the printer is connected via USB to the Mac's USB port.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong: First error message: Unable to verify the printer on your network.Unable to connect to ‘localhost’ due to an error. Would you still like to create the printer?   Second error message: "The software for the printer was installed incorrectly. Please reinstall the software from the manufacturer."

Comment: I'm trying to see if that particular driver is included with GS.  I installed mine from MacPorts.  If it's not included, it may have to be compiled.

Comment: @Allen The .ppd files is a text file, which contains driverUrl: "http://www.openprinting.org/download/printing/samsung-gdi/"  The URL is good: the files under said directory were put in a folder under downloads.  I am speculating that the .ppd file is a set of instructions, that enables the computer download a set of inputs that are processed to produce an output that is positioned for printer setup?

Comment: You should not need to compile the driver.  That's the good news.  Issue this command at the command prompt:  `gs -h | grep gdi`.  You should see two lines and in there should be both `gdi` and `samsunggdi`.  If you just issue `gs -h` by itself, you'll get the full list of supported drivers.  Let me know if it's there.

Comment: If you are on Skype, I can provide you with real-time feedback.   Catalina is now on zsh, so I had to `brew install gs`.  Yes the command returned samsunggdi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115416/discussion-between-gatorback-and-allan).